# How do I add a link to the #title property of a checkbox?

Tags: 8, navigation

I created a custom module for Drupal 8.6, and I want to post a link to my terms and conditions.

This is the code I am using.

```
namespace Drupal\commerce_agree_cgv\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneBase;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_cart\Controller\CartController;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Provides the completion message pane.
 *
 * @CommerceCheckoutPane(
 *   id = "agree_cgv",
 *   label = @Translation("Agree CGV"),
 *   default_step = "review",
 * )
 */
class AgreeCGV extends CheckoutPaneBase implements CheckoutPaneInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $link = Link::createFromRoute($this->t('my terms'), 'entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 1], ['attributes' => ['target' => '_blank']])->toString();
    $pane_form['cgv'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#default_value' => FALSE,
      '#title' => $this->t('I have read and accept', ['the general terms and conditions of business' => $link]),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#weight' => $this->getWeight(),
    ];
    return $pane_form;
  }

}
```

The link does not work. When I go to my page, the link is missing.

> [image]

The server runs on PHP 7.2.

How do I display the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$this->t('I have read and accept', ['the general terms and conditions of business' => $link])` the code would just show *I have read and accept* or its translation in the language set for the currently logged-in user, before Drupal 9.1.0. Starting from Drupal 9.1.0, it would also trigger the following error (visible in the server log).

> Support for keys without a placeholder prefix is deprecated in Drupal 9.1.0 and will be removed in Drupal 10.0.0.

The correct code to show the complete message, including the link, is the following one, which uses placeholders.

```php
$pane_form['cgv'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#default_value' => FALSE,
  '#title' => $this->t('I have read and accept <a href=":general-terms">the general terms and conditions of business</a>', [':general-terms' => Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 1], ['attributes' => ['target' => '_blank']])->toString()]),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#weight' => $this->getWeight(),
];
```

To be correctly used, the *:general-terms* placeholder must be put between quotes, as the documentation for [`FormattableMarkup::placeholderFormat()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Render%21FormattableMarkup.php/function/FormattableMarkup%3A%3AplaceholderFormat/9.3.x) says.

> Use this when using the "href" attribute, ensuring the attribute value is always wrapped in quotes:
>
> ```php
>  // Secure (with quotes):
> $this->placeholderFormat('<a href=":url">@variable</a>', [
>  ':url' => $url,
>  '@variable' => $variable,
> ]);
>
> // Insecure (without quotes):
> $this->placeholderFormat('<a href=:url>@variable</a>', [
>  ':url' => $url,
>  '@variable' => $variable,
> ]);
> ```